# Return empty string if date contains '1900'

Tags: sql-server

I have date field which has date value in format 'dd-MM-yyyy'. I need to return empty string in select if value contains '1900' or year is 1900.

I have tried the case statement and it works fine but i need to return '' instead of Null. If i replace NULL with '' then i get the normal value not ''

```
CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX('1900', StartDate) > 0 THEN NULL
ELSE StartDate
END AS SD
```

Comment: "_date field_" means `DateTime`/`Date` or `varchar` column?

Comment: '' is invalid value for datetime datatype, null or valid date are only supported values.  '' is character data.  You'd have to cast the result type to varchar to support your desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column is a date, and you want a formatted value back, then convert both sides to the relevant type, e.g.

```
CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(StartDate) = 1900 THEN ''
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 105) -- Adjust datetime format to suit -- see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
END AS SD
```

Comment: +1 - I believe datetime style 105 produces the `dd-MM-yyyy` format OP is looking for

Answer (score 3):

You could use `YEAR` instead of string methods:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN YEAR(StartDate) = 1900 
          THEN ''
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),StartDate,105)
       END AS SD
FROM dbo.TableName
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e3c9/1/0)</kbd>

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx) you can find the formats for `CONVERT`, i have used `105`(italian) for `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it with the CONVERT :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE YEAR(StartDate) WHEN 1900 THEN NULL ELSE StartDate END AS SD
```

Comment: i need to return empty string not 'NULL'

Comment: I missed that.  In that case Rowland's answer is the one you are looking for